# Retry http request with backoff - (Nestjs - axios - rxjs) throws socket hang up

Tags: node.js, http, axios, nestjs

[second-Update]: [i solved the issue by implmentig retry with promises and try & catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7TEU.png)

[first-Update]:
I tried the retrial mechanism with HTTP request with `content-type: application/json` and it works!! but my issue Is with content type `form-data`.
I guess it's similar to this problem: [Axios interceptor to retry sending FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662759/axios-interceptor-to-retry-sending-formdata)

[Services architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmcDJ.png)

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to service-a from NestJS-app.
and I want to implement retry with backoff logic.
to re-produce service-a failure, I'm restarting its docker container and make the HTTP request.
retry logic implemented as 3 retries.
first time as service-a is restarting.. throws `405 service not available` error and make retry.
all 3 retries failed with a `socket hang up` error.

[HTTP request code using axios nestjs wrapper lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1hx3.png)
[retryWithBackOff `rxjs` operator implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWNuY.png)

the first call throws a `405 Service Unavailable` error.
then application starts retries.
first retry fires after `service-a` started, failed with error `socket hang up`
first, second, and third retries failed with `socket hang up`.
[3 sockets hang up errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIKN7.png)

my expected behavior is:
when `service-a` started then the first retry fires, it should work with a successful response.

notice that 3 retries don't log to the Nginx server anything!

Answer (score 1):

While your solution probably works, it could be improved in terms of single responsibility, which RxJS can help with. I use an adapted solution of a code snippet I found once on the web (I can't find the original source any more).

```
interface GenericRetryStrategy {
  getAttempt?(): number;
  maxRetryAttempts?: number;
  scalingDuration?: number;
  maxDuration?: number;
  retryFormula?: RetryFormula;
  excludedStatusCodes?: number[]; // All errors with these codes will circumvent retry and just return the error
}

const genericRetryStrategy$ =
  ({
    getAttempt,
    maxRetryAttempts = 3,
    scalingDuration = 1000,
    maxDuration = 64000,
    retryFormula = 'constant', // time-to-retry-count interpolation
    excludedStatusCodes = [], // All errors with these codes will circumvent retry and just return the error
  }: GenericRetryStrategy = {}) =>
  (error$: Observable<unknown>): Observable<number> =>
    error$.pipe(
      switchMap((error, i) => {
        const retryAttempt = getAttempt ? getAttempt() : i + 1;

        // if maximum number of retries have been met
        // or response is a error code we don't wish to retry, throw error
        if (
          retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts ||
          excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.code)
        ) {
          return throwError(error);
        }

        const retryDuration = getRetryCurve(retryFormula, retryAttempt);
        const waitDuration = Math.min(
          maxDuration,
          retryDuration * scalingDuration,
        );

        // retry after 1000ms, 2000ms, etc …
        return timer(waitDuration);
      }),
    );
```

You would then call it like this:

```
const retryThreeTimes$ = genericRetryStrategy$({
      maxRetryAttempts: 3,
      excludedStatusCodes: [HttpStatus.PayloadTooLarge, HttpStatus.NotFound] // This will throw the error straight away
    });

this.setupUploadAttachements(url, clientApiKey, files, toPoTenantId).pipe(retryWhen(retryThreeTimes$))
```

This function/operator can now be re-used for all kinds of requests. It is very flexible. It also makes your operator logic more readable, since the complex retry logic sits somewhere else and does not “pollute” your `pipe`.

You might have to do some adjustment, since axios does return a different error payload, it seems (at least judging from your code examples). Also, if I understood your code correctly, you actually don't want to throw and error when the above error codes apply. In that case, you could add another `catchError` after the `retryWhen` and filter these codes, while returning `of([])`.